# How to accurately translate the word "hectic"?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais

I can't seem to find a proper 1-word French translation of "hectic" in the sense of 'with disjointed feverish agitation'. Context: talking about a very agitated period of someone's life, possibly a bad one.

The French word "hectique" apparently only refers to some kind of feverish medical condition...

The words I found in dictionaries such as *mouvementé*, *trépidant*, *agité*, *survolté* do not account for the feverish sense of this word.

Answer (score 5):

Although “**tumultueux/euse**” is probably used more often to describe such years or eras in world history or to describe someone’s entire life ([as in the title of this film](http://www.filmfestamiens.org/?TUMULTUEUSE-VIE-D-UN-DEFLATE-LA,2715&lang=en)) than it is to describe a particular part of someone’s life, [this entry from *Word Reference*](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/tumultueux) makes a connection between that French adjective and *hectic*:

> **tumultueux** adj    littéraire (riche en événements)
>
> tumultuous, eventful adj
>   **hectic**, turbulent adj

(here's another link to the film mentioned above which translates the original French title, [*La tumultueuse vie d'un déflaté*,](http://www.africultures.com/php/index.php?nav=film&no=8572) to *The Hectic Life of a Dismissed Worker* in English)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good one. :) And searching for more synonyms I also found 'houleux', 'chaotique', 'tourmenté'. I think the first two picture well the unfortunate side of the context I wanted to describe using 'hectic'. Still not perfect though... but we may not come any closer. :/

Answer (score 2):

According to what I found [here](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/hectic) I'd translate to: "frénétique" or "intense"

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ces deux adjectifs soient les plus appropriés pour évoquer une période de la vie de quelqu'un…

Answer (score 2):

> Context: talking about a very agitated period of s.o.'s life, possibly a bad one.

You can use « mouvementé » then. This is the most appropriate word French speakers would use. For instance : « une période mouvementée » (when refering to someone's life).

Comment: True, but it feels like the word is not strong enough in that case. I'm really talking about a nightmare-like period of s.o.'s life.

Answer (score 1):

A few words exist :

> Mouvementé

Can refer to what you mean, can be quite pejorative.

---

> Agité

But it's difficult to replace 'hectic' directly with 'agité', you would have to change the whole expression for it to fit.

---

> Trépidant

Not especially pejorative, this is what I would use instead, unless you want it to be pejorative ; in that case, consider using 'mouvementé'.

Comment: That's also what I found on the internet, but it's not pejorative enough. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think "maniaque" would match your description.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm not sure pple would catch up the meaning. Additionally, I feel that 'maniaque' refers more to the person's internal hectic state rather than his/her whole life being a mess. In the same category, we also found 'chaotique'.